# Restful service data binding using CXF

Tags: java, json, binding, cxf

Here is the requirement

```
@POST
public void updateSomething(UpdateRequest req);
```

Class UpdateRequest looks like

```
public class UpdateRequest {
private Long id;
private String name;
private String comment;
```

Now, if the client who calls this service only passes in "id" and want the service to update "id" only.

Is it possible to know that? Since we rely on CXF, which will give us NULL value for anything not provided. Is it enough to say as follows?

> From service point of view, if any field in the request is NULL, means the client hasn't passed that in